# Babel loader issues with polkadotjs and create-react-app

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-front-end

We're working to update our dApp to node 16 and update the dev config to point to the latest polkadot dev config.

We are using `customize-cra` to customize the babel loaders which looks partially as:

```
module.exports = override(
  ...addExternalBabelPlugins(
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { "useESModules": false }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-bigint',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await',
    'babel-plugin-styled-components',
  ),
  ...addBabelPlugins(
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { "useESModules": false }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-bigint',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await',
    'babel-plugin-styled-components',
  ),
```

We are getting issues as below:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:14)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export const packageInfo = {
|   name: '@polkadot/api',
>   path: import.meta && import.meta.url ? new URL('.', import.meta.url).pathname : 'auto',
|   type: 'esm',
|   version: '7.12.1'
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

I think the issue can be solved either by using a [babel transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-import-meta) or maybe not using the `import.meta.url` as can be seen in your error:

```
import.meta && import.meta.url ? new URL('.', import.meta.url).pathname : 'auto'`
```

as the starting `import.meta.url` returns this error.

Maybe a simpler solution would be to:

```
const url = new URL('.', import.meta.url);
const result = url?.pathName || 'auto';
```

**UPDATE:**
Above was not finally a correct response.
[Here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/usage/FAQ/#on-webpack-4-i-have-a-parse-error-on-importmetaurl) is a link with the solution

Comment: This is not something we have directly written, it comes from the Polkadot dependencies.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/usage/FAQ/#on-webpack-4-i-have-a-parse-error-on-importmetaurl

Comment: Following the above link leads to a solution. Thanks Nikos!

Comment: Might be worth editing the answer to include this info explicitly 